# Submit In-App Purchase details for review on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've got my game live on the App Store with my shiny brand new in-app purchases.
I had questions on some of them thus I want to change their descriptions. I did on iTunes Connect and now I have those [Pending rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw6Xu.png) and when I click on it, it says "Waiting for review" but the "In-App Purchase Details" section's status remains Approved…

Is there a way to submit them for review or is it automatic?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To submit your In-App purchases for review, you have to select to submit them for review in your App Details in iTunes Connect.

When you select the option "Ready to Upload Binary," in your details, the option should be somewhere on the page to **Submit new in-app purchases**, in roughly the same place as submitting new leaderboards, achievements, etc. Turn them on and upload your binary and they will be reviewed.